# I want to work as a freelancer in data entry. What skills are required and how can I make my profile attractive?

Tags: payment-terms, attracting-clients, working-from-home, training

I want to work as a freelancer in data entry. What skills are required? and how can I make my profile attractive?

I also want my fees by Paytm. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It all really depends on what kind of data you are adding, what your clients want, how they want data adding.

I would say it's likely they will want things in a database if you're talking about websites, such as stock etc. But it could also be things like entering numbers in Microsoft Excel.

Other skills would be maths, analytics, and data analytics. I think you should find your customers first and see what it is THEY want, and update your skills accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Data entry is very important work. I often deal with digitization/automation projects that involve data entry from non-uniform sources (e.g., invoices from different contractors) that cannot be fully automated. In such a situation, I often need and seldom find reliable data entry specialists.

When looking for a data entry specialist, I want:

- Excellent language skills and attention to detail (to minimize errors on data entry).
- Support for multiple data formats: Excel, CSV, plain text, sometimes JSON, SQL
- Ability to follow complex instructions with many special cases.
- Ability to double-check data entry by building check lists from instruction set(s).